# Allow a user to read some other users' home directories - Windows

Tags: windows, directory, user-accounts, home-directory

I have an user - reception with a home directory ("\nas\home") which I want to share it with another user only i.e.: john

I'm looking for a way around of it as we the way SMB home shares are treated with the NAS this doesn't work giving permission to this directory.

How can I do it?

Comment: In Active Directory or Workgroup ?

Comment: in Active Directory - the goal is to find a way to share the reception home directory with another user.